# Where in the world can I find a replacement schwinn cup-holder as used on many cruiser bikes for decades?

Tags: parts, cruiser, hydration, schwinn, bottle

As recently as 2018, schwinn catalogs had a “cup-holder series” of cruisers, with a plastic and foam cup holder fitted at the front between the twin top tubes. It degrades under UV, sunlight. I think it’s been around for decades.

I contacted the Schwinn importer for Australia, they just laughed at me. Clearly too hard for a fairly recent part!

So who can help me source this cup holder elsewhere, where the brand may be better supported?

Relevant models include:

Super Cruiser

Hornet

Debutante

Mark V

Starlet

Hollywood

Panther

Sprite

Corvette

I’m quite willing to buy it in the USA if someone can give me a lead. Parts catalogs for Schwinn bicycles seem to be a closely-held secret! In contrast to exercise bikes.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a photo to add?   Also, this might be something that can be 3D printed as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Per the FAQ, we don't normally do product recommendations or shopping questions. But in general, you are not the first person to prefer to have a water bottle carried near the stem, rather than lower down where the bottle cage mounts usually are. If you can't find a Schwinn-specific solution, you could try Googling for "bike cup holder" or "bike handlebar water bottle". Those should return at least a few affordable solutions which will strap to the stem and handlebar. For example, Portland Design Works makes [this one](https://www.rei.com/product/169957/portland-design-works-hot-take-beverage-holder?sku=1699570001&store=&CAWELAID=120217890009911236&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=103051232857&CATCI=aud-830183485327:pla-452552829802&cm_mmc=PLA_Google%7C21700000001700551_1699570001%7C92700056159444488%7CNB%7C71700000062146843&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw5ImwBhBtEiwAFHDZxwNikP0ykS7g_2xXKs_fdc8FeCZtQAWX-a9Sv85w_ZhBwrZK81M_6hoCiZ4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) available at REI. That puts a water bottle right in front of you while cycling. The search term "stem bar bag" will tend to return more upmarket versions geared for bikepacking that are often built by small scale manufacturers.

In general, for something that's manufacturer specific, you can ask a dealer to help you hunt parts down. However, Schwinn's current dealers are Amazon.com and a few big box stores. I have a hard time imagining that Amazon customer service would be able to spare the time to help you track down something from Schwinn, or that they would have the domain-specific knowledge to really do anything useful.